# CSS3 / Current Way to Implement Full Screen Layout

Tags: html, css, layout, fullscreen

I'm looking to implement a full screen layout that works on mobile devices and desktops without JavaScript.

```
|---|------------|
|   | <--->      |
|---|------------|
|   | <--->      |
| ^ | ^          |
|   |            |
|---| scroll     |
|   |            |
|---|------------|
```

The left part is a fixed width, the right part scales horizontally. The whole design scales vertically. The header and footer heights are fixed. The large area is scrollable while the rest is fixed.

I'd know how to implement this with absolute / fixed positioning, etc. Is there a better way with the new techniques of CSS3 that have support for this kind of layouts?

Comment: Search for css layout frameworks - there are lots online and a few sites listing/comparing them.

Answer (score 1):

short answer: percentage, floating elements and media queries.
a long answer wouldn't fit this space.

you can study [this template maker](http://www.initializr.com/) (or another i just think this is one of the best around), it will give you a nice start for learning dynamics of  responsive webdesign.